# Pairing 2 Dictionaries in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I need to implement dictionary pairing in prolog. This is what I've done:

```
pp((A, B), (B,C), RES) :-
    RES = [(A,C)].

pp((A, AA),[B|BS], RES) :-
    pp((A, AA), B, RES1),
    pp((A, AA), BS, RES2),
    append(RES1, RES2, RES).

pp([A|AS], [B|BS], C) :-
    pp(A, [B|BS], RES1),
    pp(AS, [B|BS], RES2),
    append(RES1, RES2, RES),
    list_to_set(RES, C).
pp(_, _, C) :-
    C = [].
```

Output:

```
?- pp([(a,b),(b,c)],[(b,c),(c,z)],C).
C = [ (a, c), (b, z)] ;
C = [ (a, c)] ;
C = [ (a, c)] ;
C = [ (a, c)] ;
C = [ (a, c)] ;
C = [ (a, c), (b, z)] ;
C = [ (a, c)] ;
C = [ (a, c)] ;
C = [ (a, c)] ;
C = [ (a, c)] ;
C = [ (b, z)] ;
C = [] ;
C = [] ;
C = [] ;
C = [] ;
C = [ (b, z)] ;
C = [] ;
C = [] ;
C = [] ;
C = [] ;
C = [ (b, z)] ;
C = [] ;
C = [] ;
C = [] ;
C = [] ;
C = [].

?-
```

The first result is the right answer. The question is why does the predicate pp allow C to be all the other values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prolog will try *all* alternatives it can match, then you get those results as the outcome of unexpected computation going on in your algorithm.

You are 'overloading' pp/3, using it to match *both* the list and the element.
This make little sense, because your data structure isn't recursive.

Instead of suggesting to put cuts around (a cut commits to done choices, then could help to avoid that spourious results), I think you could get the same result using some builtin, easier to apply than list_to_set/2

```
pp([],_,[]).
pp([(A,B)|As], X, [(A,C)|R]) :- select((B,C), X, Y), !, pp(As, Y, R).
% BUG ! pp([_|As], X, R) :- select(As, X, R).
pp([_|As], X, R) :- pp(As, X, R).
```

note the cut after the successful select/3, avoiding the 'skip rule' following.

*edit* to get more words from the second dictionary, let's retry the successful match:

```
pp([(A,B)|As], X, [(A,C)|R]) :- select((B,C), X, Y), !, pp([(A,B)|As], Y, R).
```

Comment: My imperative thinking mind can't understand Your code completely.

But I forgot to tell that one word can match many words and many words can match one word.

Due to my lack of knowledge in Prolog, I don't know how to change it in Your code.

However, I successfully fixed my code with cut.

Comment: Sorry, there was a bug. select/3 *removes* the matched element from the second dictionary. See my update.